# SQL Select exact rows

Tags: sql

I got some tables and now I want to determine the current rank of each customer.
I got a log table that holds all the Information when a customer got a "point" then I created a view that counts the "points" for every customer. Now I'm trying to create another view that matches the customers points with the current Rank he has. Furthermore I got a "rank" table that holds the name of the rank and the min points you need to have to reach that rank. My Problem is now that when I do

```
SELECT r.neededVisits, r.name, av.customerId
FROM Rank r, amountOfVisits av
WHERE av.amount >= r.neededVisits
```

I get something like this:
[Table Output]

[image: 1]

The left column "besuche" holds the value that is needed for that rank i.e. for the rank "gast" you need 0 visits. For the rank "Stammgast" you need 25 visits.
So I get every rank that a customer ever passed. But I just want to get the last rank for each customer
Is there any way I can do this?
Desired Result would be something like this:

[Deisred Result]

[image: 2]

The Table that holds the ranks

[Rank Table]

[image: 3]

[Rank Table Values]

[image: 4]

The table that holds the counted visits for each user

[Amount of visits for each user]

[image: 5]

[Amount of visits Table values]

[image: 6]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like

```
SELECT r.neededVisits, r.name, av.customerId
FROM Rank r, amountOfVisits av
WHERE av.amount >= r.neededVisits
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rank r2 WHERE r2.neededVisits < r.neededVisits AND av.amount >= r2.neededVisits)
```

This uses your current logic, but the final condition removes the in between ranks.

As pointed out in the comments, you should probably try to rewrite with an `inner join` which would be more like

```
SELECT r.neededVisits, r.name, av.customerId
FROM Rank r INNER JOIN amountOfVisits av
  ON av.amount >= r.neededVisits
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rank r2 WHERE r2.neededVisits < r.neededVisits AND av.amount >= r2.neededVisits)
```

I think the above is pretty readable, but a more modern method (depending on your DBMS) would be to use window functions. Something like

```
SELECT neededVisits, name, customerId
FROM
(
 SELECT r.neededVisits, r.name, av.customerId, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY av.customerId ORDER BY r.neededVisits DESC) tr
 FROM Rank r INNER JOIN amountOfVisits av
  ON av.amount >= r.neededVisits
) iq
WHERE tr=1
```

The inner query here calculates a column "tr" that is ordered DESC based on the matching ranks for that customer. The outer query gets the first one.